# How can I change the track for the freeway drive in simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I need to debug the use location for the particular track. I have checked the freeway drive that gives the track in Cupertino. I want to test the user track in  my city. is there any way to test and debug.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is - GPX FILES

GPX is a standard file format used for expressing GPS locations. The format for GPX files that Xcode looks for is fairly straightforward:

```
<gpx>
    <wpt lat="38.897678" lon="-77.036517"></wpt>
</gpx>
```

1. create and add this file to Xcode
2. Once the app is running on your device, go to Product > Debug > Simulate Location, and select the last option in the list that says “Add GPX File to Project…”, then select the Your.gpx file we just created

More info here:

http://blackpixel.com/blog/2013/05/simulating-locations-with-xcode.html
http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/04/using-xcode-to-test-location-services/
http://www.cardinalsolutions.com/cardinal/blog/mobile/2013/02/testing_a_location-a.html